# Dynamic DNS Cron Job (duckdns.org) root or user?

Tags: cron, root

I have an account with duckdns.org and on the PI 2 I would like to know if I should install and run the cron job as a user or as root.

Comment: Does it require root access? the documentation is not clear on this point, but security considerations would suggest trying it as pi and only if that does not work running either with sudo or as root.

Comment: Thanks. I boned up on Ubuntu sudo commands as a user vice root, and I love the thought that my commands are stored in the auth.log for review.

Answer (score 2):

Only if any of your scripts or applications need root access to do that, run cronjobs with such permission. Otherwise you should still using pi user or another user created only for that propruse.